# Issue passing Kendo UI grid model via Viewbag

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've got a Kendo grid Razor defined:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyApp.Models.FolderName.Whatever>()
    .Name("grid")
    ...
    ...
```

Since I'm trying to create reusable pages, I needed to define the model of the grid in the controller and pass it via ViewBag.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ViewBag.myModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    ...
    ...
```

But the above attempt fails:

[image]

It doesn't need to be via ViewBag but I need to define the model in some other way.

Comment: Are you trying to bind this grid to a model of type T or potentially dynamic objects with different properties or is it the same model that is being applied to the grid in your scenario?

Comment: @DavidShorthose, it's a model with the same properties and methods but located in a different folder. They have the same structure but the way they are filled is a bit different

Comment: @chiapa Sounds like a design problem to me. Taking identical entities and separating them into different locations is not DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). If you have multiple data types (models) that share the same properties and methods, you should use inheritance.

Comment: @Brett, they are very similar but not the same. Each one has methods that fetch data from different webservices. The properties they have are 90% the same and that could be solved via inheritance, but the methods do point at different webservice endpoints and inheritance wouldn't solve it.

Comment: @chiapa That's not entirely correct. Again, with the proper design decision, you could use inheritance for the methods. For example, could you not pass in the web service connection parameters as an argument to the method? Then you have a method that can access any web service and is easily inherited.

Comment: @Brett, with a lot of gymnastics, I could use inherited classes or even create a larger model with everything in it but that would take development time that I don't want to spare right now. I am trying to avoid that by using some quicker and simpler method of doing it, if it exists

Comment: @chiapa I understand your reluctance and frustration. I've been there myself, as I'm sure many other coders have. However (and no offense) taking the fast and easy road is how code turns into spaghetti. You're only making it harder for yourself in the long run, especially when you have to come back to your code 6 months later and apply a fix or add a feature. Inheritance makes things simpler and easier, but, yes, it will require some up-front design & development time. I don't think you're going to find some magic bullet for your problem w/o changing your design.

Answer (score 1):

I'd pass the strongly typed model into Razor view to avoid casting.

```
@model IEnumerable<MyModel>
```

then it will be like

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyModel>()    
 .Name("grid")
 ...
```

If you want to stick to ViewBag approach, then you will have to cast the data

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid((IEnumerable<MyModel>)ViewBag.myModel)
.Name("Grid")
 ...
```

Telerik has done a good job of documenting this. You can find it [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/local-data-binding).

Please note that `MyModel` here is a strongly typed one.

**Edit**

Based on comments, see if this helps you. My guess is that you have some common properties that can go in a base class like below

```
public class BaseModel
{
  public string PropertyOne{get;set;}
  public string PropertyTwo{get;set;} 
}
```

Then create child models like below:

```
public class WhateverModel:BaseModel 
{

}
public class MyModel:BaseModel 
{

}
```

Now, you can either have collection of `WhateverModel` or `MyModel` in `ViewBag.myModel`

Your view code would be like below:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid((IEnumerable<BaseModel>)ViewBag.myModel)
.Name("Grid")
...
```

This is how you can pass any model collection into your ViewBag.myModel as long as that model is inheriting from the `BaseModel`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried `@(Html.Kendo().Grid((IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.FolderName.Whatever>)ViewBag.myModel)` but then the problem remains. I have multiple models with the same name and to access the one I want I must prefix it with the folder which contains it - that must be defined dynamically

Comment: What do you mean by 'I have multiple models with the same name and to access the one I want I must prefix it with the folder which contains it' ? Are they going to have same properties but different type names? I have a solution in mind but I will need these questions answered in order to update my answer correctly.

Comment: @chiapa You seem confused. You do realize that `MyApp.Models.FolderName` is a namespace and `Whatever` is the data type, right? Just because your project folders mimic your namespace scheme is simply coincidental. The namespace can be anything you want it to be. I too am perplexed with what you mean by "multiple models...same name". Are you saying you have multiple data types named `Whatever` and each have a different namespace?

Answer (score 1):

I think your design is flawed, and you shouldn't be using viewbags at all.

Personally I dislike passing data to the view directly, and the Kendo Grid is perfectly capable of retrieving data itself. This can be as generic as you want it to be.

If you have different models with the same structure, but filled differently you should combine them into a single reusable generic model.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyApp.Models.GenericModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .DataSource(ds => ds.Read("GetGenericData", "Home", new { someParameter })
    ...
)
```

Comment: They are separated because each one is very large and they relate to different modules within the solution. Also, each one has methods that fetch data webservices, but with different endpoints to data from different sources. To create a model that gathers all of the others would create a gigantic model and I want to avoid that. For that, I can create another view that points to the model I want

Comment: @chiapa I know you're probably tired of me bringing this up, but, again, inheritance would solve every issue you just brought up.

Answer (score 0):

syntax would be like this

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid((IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.FolderName.Whatever>)ViewBag.myModel)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this way I still have to write the whole path - I want that to be dynamic and pass it as a ViewBag, for example